# Generating authentication header from azure table through objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, azure, icloud

I'm fetching data from iCloud and for that I need to generate a header (azure table storage).

I used the code below for that and it is generating the headers. But when I use these headers in my project it is showing "make sure that the value of authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I googled a lot and tried many codes but in vain.

Can anyone kindly please help me with where I'm going wrong in this code.

```
-(id)generat
{
    NSString *messageToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", dateString,AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, tableName];

    NSString *key = @"asasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasas==";

    const char *cKey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    const char *cData = [messageToSign cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    NSString *hash = [Base64 encode:HMAC];

    NSLog(@"Encoded hash: %@", hash);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://my url"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SharedKeyLite %@:%@",AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, hash] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request addValue:dateString forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-ms-date"];

    [request addValue:@"application/atom+xml, application/xml"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request addValue:@"UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Charset"];

    NSLog(@"Headers: %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
     return request; 
}

-(NSString*)rfc1123String:(NSDate *)date
{
    static NSDateFormatter *df = nil;
    if(df == nil)
    {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
        df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        df.dateFormat = @"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'";
    }
    return [df stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: @meccan no.im not using ARC.You have any idea about whats wrong in my code.

Comment: ok, so you leak the "HMAC" and the "df" object

Comment: @meccan thats ok.im now working on a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like perhaps you're missing a newline:

```
NSString *messageToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", dateString,AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, tableName];
```

I don't know Objective-C, but I would expect the format to be `@"%@\n/%@/%@"` (if that's how newlines in string literals work in this programming language).

Also, I think you'll need these two headers:

```
DataServiceVersion:1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion:1.0;NetFx
```

**EDIT**: It occurs to me that those headers might be present in another part of your code. You also might want the `x-ms-version` header (also may be present elsewhere in the code). **/EDIT**

I can't in good conscience *not* point out that it's a bad idea to put your storage key on a client (like a phone). Anyone who gets your app can extract the key and use it to delete all your data, upload their private DVD collection, etc. Your storage key is a secret and as such should never be distributed to clients.